# similarity at Line parallel to another line to make Z letter

Tags: geometry

[image]
$AB = BC =CD =5$ cm. AB // CD.  DE // BC. DE = 2 cm. What is the length of $BF$?

Comment: Possibly you forgot to add $DE\parallel BC$.

Comment: That's right. Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $DE\parallel BC$ (otherwise we haven't enough data) one gets:
$$
AB:BF=CG:FC=DG:DE,
\quad\hbox{that is:}\quad
5:BF=(5-DG):(5-BF)=DG:2.
$$
Solve for $BF$ and $DG$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Complete the figure to get the point $H$ such that $BCDH$ is a parallelogram.

- It is immediate that $HE+ED=BC=5$ so $HE=3$
- By construction we also have $AC=CH$ so by applying Thales $CF=\frac 12 HE=\frac 32$
- Finally $CF+BF=BC=5$ so $BF=\frac 72$